# Mongoose: MongoError no geoSearch Index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose version 5.1.5, Mongodb version 3.0.10
When I use mongoose Model.geoSearch method, it gives me an error saying MongoError: No geoSearch Index
Below is the schema

```
var hotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name:   {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
stars:  {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    max: 5,
    "default": 0
},
services:   [String],
description: String,
photos: [String],
currency : String,
reviews : [reviewSchema],
rooms : [roomSchema],
location : {
  address : String,
  // Always store coordinates longitude (East/West), latitude (North/South) 
  order.
  coordinates : {
    type : [Number],
    index: '2dsphere'
  }
}
});
```

Below is the geoSearch method

```
    var geoOptions = {
    near: [lng,lat],
    maxDistance: 2000,
    limit: 5
}
Hotel
    .geoSearch({coordinates: '2dsphere'}, geoOptions, function(err, results, stats){
        if(err){
            console.log('Error: '+err);
            res
                .json(err);
        } else{
            console.log("Geo Results " + results);
            console.log("Geo Stats "+ stats);
            res
                .status(200)
                .json(results);
        }

    });
```

And here is what appears in the console
    Error: MongoError: no geoSearch index

As it says there is no geoSearch index thus I have added a 2dsphere index which can be seen in the schema.
Please can anyone help me what I am doing wrong.

Updated
I get the following when I use

```
    db.hotels.getIndexes()
    [
     {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "meanhotel.hotels"
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "location.coordinates" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "location.coordinates_2dsphere",
            "ns" : "meanhotel.hotels",
            "background" : true,
            "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "location" : 1
            },
            "name" : "location_1",
            "ns" : "meanhotel.hotels",
            "background" : true
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "coordinates" : 1
            },
            "name" : "coordinates_1",
            "ns" : "meanhotel.hotels",
            "background" : true
    },
    {
            "v" : 2,
            "key" : {
                    "coordinates" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "coordinates_2dsphere",
            "ns" : "meanhotel.hotels",
            "background" : true,
            "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    }
 ]
```

Comment: can you run the following from mongodb console `db.<replace-with-your-collection-name>.getIndexes()` and check the index was created in the first place.

Comment: I used what you asked for you can see the edited post. And one more thing what do I write in the first param (which is the condition) of geoSearch based on my schema

Comment: Does anyone have any idea? Any suggestions would mean a lot to me!!

Comment: Can you select my answer or add feedback as to why my answer isn't correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The geoSearch function requires the use of a `geoHaystack` index and not a 2dSphere index. I was unable to figure out how to create the geoHaystack index using mongoose but you can create the index via the mongo shell.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geohaystack/

If you're looking to do a geo query in 5.x that uses a 2dSphere index, you'll do a normal `find` or `findOne` query with `$near` or `$nearSphere` operator in the query.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/query/near/
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/